# Residue Theorem on a circumference

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I think I am to solve this integral using the Residue Theorem
$$\oint_C\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}dz$$
Where $C$ is the circumference $|z|=3$, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Any help?

Comment: What have you figured out? Where are the residues?

Comment: If residues don't mesh with you, use the Cauchy formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}$$ has simple poles at $-2$ and $2.$ The contour $C$ encloses those poles, since $|-2|=|2|\lt|3|.$ Therefore, you can use the residue theorem and conclude that $$\oint_C\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}\,\mathrm{d}z=2\pi{i}\left[\operatorname{Res}\left(-2,\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}\right)+\operatorname{Res}\left(2,\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}\right)\right]=2\pi{i}\left[\lim_{z\to-2}(z+2)\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}+\lim_{z\to2}(z-2)\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}\right].$$ You should be able to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The residue theorem says that your integral is equal to $2 \pi i (\alpha + \beta)$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are the residues of $$\frac{e^z}{(z+2)(z-2)}$$at $-2, 2$ respectively.

Use the fact that if $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function in a punctured neighborhood of a point $z_0$, with at most a simple pole there, then the residue of $f$ at $z_0$ is

$$\lim\limits_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z).$$